# Graph design (for neo4j) for sports tournaments

Tags: graph, neo4j

I want to use a graph database for a web application that tracks the players, matches, leagues  for a given sport say volleyball. Below is the 1st level model I came up with. I would like to  support the below statistics for this web application

Player

1. Show all the leagues played by a player.
2. Show all the matches played by a player in each league.
3. Player's current team and his previous teams.
4. How many times the player was a captain and all the leagues for which he was the captain.

Team

1. All leagues played by a team.
2. How many times the team was a winner or runner.

**NOTE: Right click on the image and open it in a new tab to see the original image.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model looks good, however after looking at your use cases, I have a few questions/suggestions:

## Query

I'll give these in Cypher as it's easiest to show in this format.

Player

***Show all the leagues played by a player.***

```
START player=node:Player('indexForPlayer')
MATCH player-[PLAYED]->match-[PART_OF]->league
RETURN league
```

***Show all the matches played by a player in each league.***

```
START player=node:Player('indexForPlayer')
MATCH player-[PLAYED]->match-[PART_OF]->league
RETURN match, collect(league)
```

***Player's current team and his previous teams.***

```
START player=node:Player('indexForPlayer')
MATCH player-[BELONGED_TO]->team
RETURN team
```

***How many times the player was a captain and all the leagues for which he was the captain.***

```
How do you determine if they were a captain of a league?
```

Team
***How many times the team was a winner or runner.***
You might want to put this as a relationship such as `(match)-[WINNER]->(team)` this way to find out how many wins your team has, all you have to do is count the `WINNER` relationship.

## Data Model

Add a property to the `Match` node for date played. I'm unfamiliar with sports, but Year may not be enough if they can swap teams within a year, however `Neo4j` doesn't really have a good method for dealing with time, other than a 'seconds since epoch ` type system.

Comment: +1. Since it's teams that play matches, can you change the reference of player-[PLAYED]->match to include/be team-[PLAYED]->match? - That is a good observation. But the reason I have to made it this way is because, a Team always has buffer players for e.g only 6 players can play a given volleyball match but there can be 10-12 total players in the team. This model allows me to capture the playing 6 thus providing more accurate results for the question: Show all the matches played by a player in each league. Do you think I can answer this question using a different model?

Comment: If you link match to the player, like you have for Match L1-01, It's not possible to tell the exact teams, as 'John' is with both the Broncos and Falcons, so he could have been playing for either team which that match was going on. --- A player can BELONG_TO only one team per league. That is why the BELONG_TO is qualified with a "in_year" property. Any improvisations on top of this are welcome.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to represent the fact that a player has been playing for the same team every year? For e.g. John BELONGED_TO Broncos "in_year" 2011, 2012 and 2013 etc? I can't have same kind of relationship type between same nodes multiple-times right?

Comment: No, you can have the the same relationship type multiple times between the same nodes.